# How to calculate lines of code, comments and docstrings for a Python module?

Tags: python, static-analysis, lines-of-code

Is there a tool or snippet that produces the following output in some form:

```
lines_of_code = 98
lines_of_comments = 24
lines_of_documentation = 11
```

**NOTE 1**: I will then try to feed this data to [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to graph.

**NOTE 2**: I am aware that [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) counts comments but I would like to separately count comments and docstrings.

Comment: I think it's feasible to write a simple script to do this calculation, if those 3 are what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Look at PyLint: http://www.logilab.org/857

Comment: If I am not mistaken PyLint actually imports modules. For a simple static analysis I wouldn't want this.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Pylint does use static analyis. It does not import the code under examination.